# Is there an additional argument to add for JSON.stringify(object,function,spacer)? '\n' or '\t' is not adding new line to the properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

I have a JSON object:

```
var outputJson = {
"Movie": selectedMovie,
"Genre": selectedGenre,
"Director": selectedDirector,
};
```

Then I add it to the division I have created.

```
$('jsonResult').text(JSON.stringify(outputJson,null,'\n')
```

This gives output as:

```
{
"Movie": selectedMovie,"Genre": selectedGenre,"Director": selectedDirector,
}
```

There is no new line added can we add a new line after each value?

```
{
"Movie": selectedMovie,
"Genre": selectedGenre,
"Director": selectedDirector,
}
```

Comment: Use the `white-space: pre;` style in the DIV so it won't reformat it. And use a fixed-width font.